# SQL determine if a number of consecutive months have passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns 1 indicating agent id, one indicating which level they are (Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced) and on indicate the month end date they reached that level.

If the sample data looks like this

```
360123, Beginner, 1/22/2011
360123, Null, 2/22/2011
360123, Beginner, 3/22/2011
360123, Intermediate, 4/22/2011
360123, Beginner, 5/22/2011
360123, Beginner, 6/22/2011
```

How do I design a query which will tell me which agents made all the beginner goals for 4 consecutive months from 3/22 to 6/22?

Wow, thank you all for the help!

How about for 4 months out of a 6 month period where the first month is any month you hit one of the goals?

Comment: In this case you are looking for 4 consecutive months and your `WHERE` clause only covers 4 months (Mar,Apr,May,Jun). Will that always be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Sample data and example below.  Basically, group by the ID and search for a count of distinct months.

```
DECLARE @T table (id int, lvl varchar(100), datefield smalldatetime)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(360123, 'Beginner', '1/22/2011'),
(360123, Null, '2/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Beginner', '3/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Intermediate', '4/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Beginner', '5/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Beginner', '6/22/2011')

SELECT ID
FROM @T
WHERE Lvl = 'Beginner'
AND datefield BETWEEN '3/1/2011' AND '6/30/2011 23:59:59'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(MONTH(DateField))) = 4
```

Comment: Seems to miss the **consecutive** requirement (with the current `WHERE` clause)

Comment: @MartinSmith - good point, I half used his data and half used his posted logic.  Only using the logic now!

Comment: Nitpicking: It would work for 4 or 5 or even 12 months but not for 13 or more.

Comment: @ypercube - very valid point.  That is a limitation of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Select id from table_name where date ='6/22/2011' and level ='Beginner')
intersect
(Select id from table_name where date ='5/22/2011' and level ='Beginner')
intersect

(Select id from table_name where date ='4/22/2011' and level ='Beginner')
intersect 

(Select id from table_name where date ='3/22/2011' and level ='Beginner')
```

Comment: -1 - `Intersects` isn't a valid keyword, you use the same date in every query (none of which are valid dates), and even with proper syntax this requires him to key in each date manually, and a subquery per date/month.

Comment: DV removed.  It's still a super inefficient way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM TableX
WHERE level = 'Beginner'
  AND datefield >= '2011-03-22' 
  AND datefield < '2011-06-23'
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield)) = 4
   AND ( YEAR(MAX(datefield))*12+MONTH(MAX(datefield)) )
     - ( YEAR(MIN(datefield))*12+MONTH(MIN(datefield)) ) = 4 - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Main trick is to create "artificial" Id to use it as anchor in recursive CTE:

DECLARE @T TABLE (
        Id        INT          ,
        Lvl       VARCHAR (100),
        Datefield SMALLDATETIME);

```
INSERT  INTO @T
VALUES (360123, 'Beginner', '1/22/2011'),
(360123, NULL, '2/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Beginner', '3/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Intermediate', '4/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Beginner', '12/22/2011'),
(360123, 'Beginner', '01/22/2012');

DECLARE @BeginTime AS DATETIME = '1/22/2011';

DECLARE @EndTime AS DATETIME = '6/22/2012';

WITH   M
AS     (SELECT DISTINCT Id,
                        MONTH(datefield) AS Mth,
                        YEAR(datefield) AS Yr,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield)) AS RN
        FROM   @T AS T
        WHERE  Lvl = 'Beginner'
               AND T.Datefield >= @BeginTime
               AND T.Datefield <= @EndTime),
       C (Id, RN, MonthsInARow, Mth, Yr)
AS     (SELECT M.Id,
               RN,
               CAST (1 AS INT),
               Mth,
               Yr
        FROM   M
        WHERE  RN = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT M.Id,
               M.RN,
               CASE 
               WHEN M.Mth = C.Mth + 1
                         OR (M.Mth = 1
                             AND C.Mth = 12
                             AND M.Yr = C.yr + 1) THEN C.MonthsInARow + 1 ELSE 1 
               END,
               M.Mth,
               M.Yr
        FROM   M
               INNER JOIN
               C
               ON M.Id = C.Id
                  AND M.RN = C.RN + 1)
SELECT [C].[Id],MAX([C].[MonthsInARow]) MAXMonth
FROM   C
GROUP BY [Id]
```